# Review queues difficulty separating

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I am going through the review queue and I stumble upon questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48255886/invalid-token-error) quite often.

The question follows all rules according to the How To Ask A Question guide but I see that quite a few people go as far as marking it as Unsalvageable just because it is clearly an error by the user that doesn't have much programming knowledge.

I'm not saying the question is a super good question, but I feel like questions like these might get drowned in Unsalvageables just because reviewers are being a bit "elitist" and not realizing some of these questions might be done by total newbies that really DO need an answer or at least a comment.

Is there any system in place to avoid this?

Can there be a fourth option such as "Format is OK but Question is basic" or something so that we don't just go straight away to not allowing it on the site?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the fundamental tenets here, is trying to develop content that is useful to future visitors. So, I will start by responding to this question:

> Is there any system in place to avoid this?  (i.e.: closing questions)

Closing question is not to be avoided. In fact, it is a big reason Stack Overflow is successful. Having to wade through much less irrelevant content, makes the Stack Exchange sites popular.

You also tried to make the point:

> ... because reviewers are being a bit "elitist" and not realizing some of these questions ... that really DO need an answer ...

The fact that the questioner needs an answer is irrelevant. We are trying to make answers that might be useful to the next person. Helping the questioner is supposed to just be a by-product. If it not likely to be useful to someone else because of a simple mistake, then this close reason (the reason on the question you linked) applies:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: I see your point and maybe expressed myself wrongly, I meant need an answer that explains (in this case) how language is structured but yes it is very basic